# GitHub Authentication Issue - git 2.6.2 - Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 - HelloWorld.md Markdown File

Tags: git, github, markdown, osx-yosemite

**GitHub Authentication Issue when creating HelloWorld.md markdown file and using Git to push file to repository on GitHub**
(for The Data Scientist's Toolbox Project on Coursera)

**Git Version 2.6.2**
_  **Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5**

Three images show steps followed up until issue.

**Step # 1 - Image link shown in first comment below**

**Step # 2**

[image: Step 2]

**Step # 3**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/elMZp.png]

Step # 3 Image shows GitHub authentication issue in Terminal. Will accept GitHub username, but will not accept password... **it does not allow ANY typing ability/access at all to answer password question prompt.**

How do I gain access?
Authentication issue forums solutions have not worked so far.
Help much appreciated!

Comment: Image of Step # 1: ![**Step #1**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CZEHv.png).

Comment: Are you typing your password correctly? The password prompt doesn't echo it back, but it does let you type it.

Answer (score 0):

Would you still have the issue nowadays (2022), you would need as a password a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/set-up-git#next-steps-authenticating-with-github-from-git).

Token authentication is [required since Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

Using a [credential helper](https://gist.github.com/nepsilon/0fd0c779f76d7172f12477ba9d71bb66) ([`osxkeychain`](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)) to cache that password /token will help you avoid entering said token on every push.